# How to read the active ISAPI filters properties of IIS

Tags: iis, isapi

I want to know how many ISAPI filters are active on IIS. And I also want to read the metadata properties of these active ISAPI filters in C#.

I have created an ISAPI filter dll and added it to IIS. I can see that filter in "inetmgr" but I want to get the same information through C#. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ADSI

The path is "IIS://LocalHost/W3SVC/Filters"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525344(VS.90).aspx

And you can get access to that in c# using DirectoryEntry 's

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315716

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://LocalHost/W3SVC/Filters");
foreach (DirectoryEntry child in de.Children) {
 child.Name
 child.Properties["SomeProperty"].Value
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have created a ISAPI filter dll and added with IIS. I can see that filter in inetmgr but I am unable to get the information about the same.

Comment: is it assigned to all sites, or one particular site? you might have to look at the site's filter "IIS://LocalHost/W3SVC/%websiteid%/Filters"

Comment: Its giving n error: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry' because 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Yes i had updated it Its giving only count 5 that doesn't contains my ISAPI filter.

Comment: I am doing this:private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/Filters");
            foreach (DirectoryEntry child in de.Children) 
            {                
                label1.Text = string.Concat(child.Name, "+" ,child.Properties["Status"].Value);
            }
        }